# Navigating to decoded URL doesn't elicit the same action as navigating to the encoded URL

Tags: asp.net, url, base64, urlencode

Trying to understand why pasting the first link works but not the second one.

Breakdown of the URL, for a clearer view:

Encoded version: [works]

```
http%3A%2F%2FsomeSite.com
%2FDownload.ashx
%3Frequest
%3DIL7zxW6ETqiYU6cThSNKL8MpY
%252bCRIVFZAVhd8DYPG85C1Uhdd
%252f2hqqmoObeNmuS3dg4bDgGBb0kUUxGZhej89kTaLBHBXS
%252bq3tlaEk2uMEcbWlUZzZQs00sirwZ2IvAvoSpU7HC3N1FaYSNciQ4iHNNmTU
%252f6uMypNlPOJ6enlbZ1OrrYODkaMRdRfGKEba
%252brusdryM4gp
%252bopi1a0gNuMQVCtj
%252bAvDcgXGOcZPNhPAnE
%253d&version=Ma88r6Z6t2JQcnVhVXgp0A%3D%3D
```

Decoded version: [doesn't work]

```
http://someSite.com
/Download.ashx
?request=
IL7zxW6ETqiYU6cThSNKL8MpY
+CRIVFZAVhd8DYPG85C1Uhdd
/2hqqmoObeNmuS3dg4bDgGBb0kUUxGZhej89kTaLBHBXS
+q3tlaEk2uMEcbWlUZzZQs00sirwZ2IvAvoSpU7HC3N1FaYSNciQ4iHNNmTU
/6uMypNlPOJ6enlbZ1OrrYODkaMRdRfGKEba
+rusdryM4gp
+opi1a0gNuMQVCtj
+AvDcgXGOcZPNhPAnE
=&version=Ma88r6Z6t2JQcnVhVXgp0A==
```

- If I paste the first link in the browser - it works. A file download automatically starts.
- If I paste the second link in the browser - page says Bad request.

Can anyone clarify it for me why the second one doesn't work?

Comment: You have decoded the original url twice it, that's not how it works. Do the decoding once, and then pass that url to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the `URLencode`tag:

> To “URL encode” or “percent encode” text means to encode it for use in a URL. Some characters are not valid when used as-is in URLs, and so much be URL-encoded (percent-encoded) when appearing in URLs.

The encoding was used for a reason, here because the [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) values for the `request` and `version` parameters contains `+`, `/` and `=` which have their own meaning in URLs and therefore need to be URL-encoded.